# Using <dfn> in a <table>?

Tags: html, list, html-table

Is the use of `<dfn>` in a `<table>` semantically valid if the definition of the wrapped term is in the subsequent `<td>`? Is this the correct use of `<dfn>` or must it specifically be used in a paragraph or definition list, as [stated on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Element/dfn). I would like to format my list like this:

[image: Using dfn in a table]

My logic says it should be allowed with the following code:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td><dfn>Attack</dfn></td>
        <td>Time (in ms) before the compressor will begin to work after the audio level goes beyond the threshold.</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><dfn>Release</dfn></td>
        <td>Time (in ms) before the compressor will cease to work after the audio level drops beneath the threshold.</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><dfn>Ratio</dfn></td>
        <td>The amount of compression to be applied.</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><dfn>Threshold</dfn></td>
        <td>A level in dB which, if the signal surpasses, the compressor will begin working.</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: @JohnConde - First paragraph. Is it semantically valid.

Comment: @JohnConde I made an edit with a better explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you look at [the spec](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/text-level-semantics.html#the-dfn-element)?

> The `dfn` element represents the defining instance of a term. The [paragraph](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/dom.html#paragraph), [description list group](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/grouping-content.html#the-dl-element), or [section](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/dom.html#sectioning-content-0) that is the nearest ancestor of the dfn element must also contain the definition(s) for the term given by the dfn element.

Your code fragment does not contain any of the three valid ancestor, so on its own is invalid. However, I believe the `<body>` is classed as a section, which might make your usage allowable.

Comment: I am using the table inside an `<article>`, which is clearly defined as a section in the link you provided to the spec? The table is used only to neatly format each definition.

Comment: @JoeJ: Based on that definition alone, I think you're OK. However, the spec doesn't define whether multiple definitions can be in the same container, and seems to allow things like `<p><dfn>A</dfn> definition of B, <dfn>B</dfn> definition of A</p>` which is obviously nonsensivcal

Comment: I think I'm going to go for it. In my eyes, the table is logical and I've used `<article>` as a sectioning element, as recommended. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Yes! According to [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_phrase_elements.asp%20w3schools),  is a phrase (inline) tag.

However, they also advise:

> The `<em>`, `<strong>`, `<dfn>`, `<code>`, `<samp>`, `<kbd>`, and `<var>` tags are
>   all phrase tags. They are not deprecated, but it is possible to
>   achieve richer effect with CSS.

Comment: Thanks, but we are talking about W3Schools here. I tend to distrust information that comes from that site, as do many others...

Comment: I had no idea. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: [W3Fools](http://w3fools.com/) says it all. I always use the [Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/).

Comment: Noted. I've always found the way w3schools organizes their information annoying, but I never took the time to look for an alternative. Even at first glance (or just judging from the title!) the Mozilla site is loads better...thanks again!